# How to use OPENQUERY to properly execute a Stored Procedure that updates a linked server table?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I'm using `OPENQUERY` to execute Stored Procedures on a linked server. 
I managed to find a way to do it, by using the following:

```
SELECT *    
FROM   OPENQUERY(
[LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV],  
'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [Database_Name_Example].Data.usp_GetNames 5,''S''')   
GO
```

The reason I use `SET FMTONLY OFF` and `SET NOCOUNT ON` is because when I tried the code above without them, this message appeared:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot process the object "EXEC [Database_Name_Example].Data.usp_GetNames 5,'S'". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Reading a lot online helped me find the answer. This blog for example: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY

So far so good, until I stomped into a Stored Procedure that use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` some tables on the linked server. When I execute the `OPENQUERY` I get the results from the `SELECT` statement but I noticed that it does not update the table.

The Stored Procedure goes like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Data.usp_GetNames (@year tinyint=NULL, @online char(1)=NULL)
if @online = 'S'    
  BEGIN
    select nam_codig, nam_desc from Names
    where nam_status = 'P'
    order by nam_date

    UPDATE Names
    SET nam_status = 'S'
    where nam_status = 'P'
END
```

When I execute it directly in the linked server it updates the table, so the second time I execute it, there will be no more `nam_status = 'P'`

But if I execute it with `OPENQUERY` the results are the same, it doesn't `UPDATE` it just select the data.

What can I do to allow the permissions?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What login and security context is your Linked server configued?  Is it same login when you connect directly to that server? It sounds to me that your linked server is configued with a different login than the login when directly connected .

Comment: @AdamYan I'm using the same login

Comment: Could you do me a favor: under CurrentServer in SSMS
- open 'Server Object' tab
- open 'Linked Servers' tab
- Right Click on 'LINKEDSRV\SQLSRV'
- Switch to Security tab
then tell me what you see here.

Comment: @AdamYan I'm seeing this: https://www.brentozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Picture11.png those same options are selected.

Comment: Are you using 'sa' accout to connect to the server or Windows Authentication with you windows account?

Comment: @AdamYan I'm always using 'sa' account to connect to the server

Comment: I am not sure where went wrong if the accounts are same. Maybe you can try to include the schema for all objects in your procudure. (dbo.names instead of names)

Comment: @AdamYan I tried including the schema, but is not working